# How to access the values of the output of hidden layer neurons in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

MATLAB doesn't allow one layer with more then one type of transfer function in neural network toolbox. So, I want to create 2 hidden layers, one with hyperbolic tangent transfer function and other with rbf neurons.

But I need to pass the output of the first hidden layer directly for the output layer. I'm thinking of changing the output of the second hidden layer, so that it becomes equal to the output of the first hidden layer. For that I need to access the values of the outputs of the hidden layers.
I've opened the `traingd` function and I think what I want is in some part of this code:

```
for epoch=0:param.epochs

    % Stopping Criteria
    if isMainWorker
        current_time = etime(clock,startTime);
        [userStop,userCancel] = nntraintool('check');
        if userStop, tr.stop = 'User stop.'; calcNet = best.net;
        elseif userCancel, tr.stop = 'User cancel.'; calcNet = original_net;
        elseif (perf <= param.goal), tr.stop = 'Performance goal met.'; calcNet = best.net;
        elseif (epoch == param.epochs), tr.stop = 'Maximum epoch reached.'; calcNet = best.net;
        elseif (current_time >= param.time), tr.stop = 'Maximum time elapsed.'; calcNet = best.net;
        elseif (gradient <= param.min_grad), tr.stop = 'Minimum gradient reached.'; calcNet = best.net;
        elseif (val_fail >= param.max_fail), tr.stop = 'Validation stop.'; calcNet = best.net;
        end

        % Training record & feedback
        tr = nntraining.tr_update(tr,[epoch current_time perf vperf tperf gradient val_fail]);
        statusValues = [epoch,current_time,best.perf,gradient,val_fail];
        nn_train_feedback('update',archNet,rawData,calcLib,calcNet,tr,status,statusValues);
        stop = ~isempty(tr.stop);
    end

    % Stop
    if isParallel, stop = labBroadcast(mainWorkerInd,stop); end
    if stop, return, end

    % Gradient Descent
    if isMainWorker
        dWB = param.lr * gWB;
        WB = WB + dWB;
    end

    calcNet = calcLib.setwb(calcNet,WB);
    [perf,vperf,tperf,gWB,gradient] = calcLib.perfsGrad(calcNet);

    % Validation
    if isMainWorker
        [best,tr,val_fail] = nntraining.validation(best,tr,val_fail,calcNet,perf,vperf,epoch);
    end
end
```

I found where the biases and synapses are updated, but I've not been able to find where the values of the output of neurons are set. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two custom networks which will have no hidden layers, then you can see the outputs directly using the 2 different functions. See the documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/create-and-train-custom-neural-network-architectures.html

You can also manually calculate them using the weights and bias.

`input_weights = cell2mat(net.iw) // getting the input weights
bias = net.b{1} //choosing the bias of the first layer
hidden_layer1 = tanh(input*input_weights+repmat(bias,1,input_size)) //the dot product of the input and input_weights will give some matrix, hence why the bias must be the same size`

On a side note: I found this tutorial helpful in understanding how basic neural networks work - https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Comment: Thanks! At realy a i haven't done that. But your answer was usefull. In this documentation there is an exaplanation of how chose what layers are conected with each other and what layers are conected with the inputs and outputs.